# React sticky via useEffect and scroll event listener weird flicker

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, use-effect

I've made a conditional sticky bar based on scroll position, today I noticed that it has a odd flicker effect (it adds and removes the sticky class very fast on loop) when you reach the given height from the top. When you're above or below it, it works as expected

I tried to change the height from the top, or to use a initial position from top as a condition for the useEffect, but it's the same.

Anyone had the same issue with React before?

My code is:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import styles from './xxx.module.scss'
import {tagsStore, mobileStore} from '@/utils/store'
import ScrollContainer from 'react-indiana-drag-scroll'

export default function MyComponent() {
    const [sticky, setSticky] = useState(false)

    const tags = tagsStore(state => state.tags)
    const isMobile = mobileStore(state => state.isMobile)

    const handler = () => {
        setSticky(window.pageYOffset >= 240)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handler, { passive: true })
        
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handler, { passive: true });
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {!isMobile && tags.length > 0 &&
                <div className={sticky ? styles.tagsListBoxSticky : (styles.tagsListBox + " mt-3")}>
                    <ScrollContainer>
                        ...
                    </ScrollContainer>
                </div>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```